# Move sprite in Andengine

Tags: android, andengine, sprite, screen-resolution

I want to move sprite on yaxis with some a consistent speed current I am doing just decrement from height of screen to 0 with a constant value. here is the code

```
this.engine.registerDrawHandler(new IDrawHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onDraw(GLState pGLState, Camera pCamera) {
            ballon.setpostiton(ballon.getX(), ballon.getY() - 1);
        }

    });
```

But I am not getting consistent when I move my code to different sprite. On small device its ends earlier as compared to large resolution devices and on this more I have passed FillResolutionPolicy in my andengine option.

Please tell me a consistent way to move sprite in Andengine.

Comment: Just follow this link and you problem will be solved https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine/blob/GLES2/src/org/andengine/entity/modifier/MoveYModifier.java

Answer (score 9):

```
MoveXModifier mod1=new MoveXModifier(constanttime,fromX,toX);
sprite.registerEntityModifier(mod1);
```

Use this modifier for x movement.

```
MoveYModifier mod1=new MoveYModifier(constanttime,fromY,toY);
sprite.registerEntityModifier(mod1);
```

Use this modifier for Y movement.

```
MoveModifier mod1=new MoveModifier(constanttime,fromX,toX,fromY,toY);
sprite.registerEntityModifier(mod1);
```

Use this modifier for X and  Y movement.

Comment: what is constant time? It is the duration of the animation?

Answer (score 5):

You might have a look onto [AndEngine Examples](https://code.google.com/p/andengineexamples/) - especially the [Moving Ball Example](https://code.google.com/p/andengineexamples/source/browse/src/org/anddev/andengine/examples/MovingBallExample.java) should be interesting for you. You can also download the AndEngineExamples from the Play Store to see what they do.

Comment: MoveYModifier class should exactly do what you are looking for.

https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine/blob/GLES2/src/org/andengine/entity/modifier/MoveYModifier.java

Comment: You have to use simple MoveModifier through which you can move in both x and y coordinate.